# jhipster assets for angular

Tags: angular, webpack, jhipster

I have sample jhipster app with angular as a front-end. The folder structure is

```
src
|-webapp
|--app
|---content
|----images
|-----jhipster_family_member_0.svg
```

How webpack understands that content folder is assets? My best guess was looking into angular.json (https://codinglatte.com/posts/angular/working-with-assets-styles-and-scripts-in-angular) but there is nothing related to "assets" there.

You can find code here: https://github.com/tillias/microservice-catalog

Answer (score 2, accepted):

JHipster 6 and older versions does not use Angular CLI build process so editing `angular.json` has no impact.

What you are looking for is in `webpack/webpack.common.js` in the configuration of `CopyWebpackPlugin`.

More generally all JHipster webpack configuration is in `webpack` directory.

This will change in JHipster 7.